# ajax request with no onreadystatechange

Tags: ajax

function loadXMLDocLogout()
{

```
var xmlhttpLogOut;   
 xmlhttpLogOut=new XMLHttpRequest();
  //xmlhttpLogOut.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
     if (xmlhttpLogOut.readyState==4 && xmlhttpLogOut.status==200)
     {
         document.getElementById("loadingDiv").style.display="none";

     }
     else
        document.getElementById("loadingDiv").style.display="block";
  }
 xmlhttpLogOut.open("GET","http://www.mysite.me/logout.php?LogOut=1",false);    
xmlhttpLogOut.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
xmlhttpLogOut.send(null);
```

}

The above code works perfectly despite of line
xmlhttpLogOut.onreadystatechange=function() 
being commented!

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The above code works perfectly

Of course it will, it is valid javascript code.

The `if (xmlhttpLogOut.readyState==4 && xmlhttpLogOut.status==200)` will fail and so

```
else
        document.getElementById("loadingDiv").style.display="block";
```

will be executed.

But does it produce the same result as the xmlhttpLogOut.onreadystatechange=function() not being commented? That is the element getting hidden (if it is already visible)? I doubt.

Did you try all possible test cases?

(To begin with, was the `loadingDiv` div hidden before the Ajax request was sent?)

Comment: Thanks Nivas.
Actually when the line 
xmlhttpLogOut.onreadystatechange=function() is uncommented, loadingDiv  doesnt appear and thats the problem. BTW when i commented the same line everything worked fine!